# SendMessage to Notepad++ to open a file

Tags: c#, winapi, notepad++, sendmessage

I am trying to programmatically open a file in notepad++ using `SendMessage` but I'am having no luck.
I figured that because I can drag and drop a file onto Notepad++ and it will open it, that a `SendMessage` would work.

Declarations:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, int wParam, string lParam);
```

Method:
I launch Notepad++ using `Process.Start`:

```
IntPtr cHwnd = FindWindowEx(pDocked.MainWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "Scintilla", null);
SendMessage(cHwnd, WM_SETTEXT, 0, "C:\Users\nelsonj\Desktop\lic.txt");
```

When `SendMessage` executes it will send my text into the 'edit' section of Notepad++ instead of opening the file.
Any help would be great.

Comment: As far as i know notepad++ runs normally as a single instance application. So if you start notepad++ using `Process.Start` a new tab should open.

Comment: A couple of guesses: Old fashioned DDE (and, no, I don't remember how that works).  The other way would be to put a file object onto the clipboard, and then send a Drag/Drop message (or sequence of messages) to Notepad++

Comment: If you do try @Pretasoc's `Process.Start` suggestion, I'm pretty sure you'll need to set `UseShellExecute` to `true` (in a `ProcessStartInfo`).  But, then again...

Comment: Process.Start should be the right way to go

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want to open a file in Notepad++, you can just start a new [Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Diagnostics.Process);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2):

- set the path of the file you want to open to the `Arguments` property of the [ProcessStartInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.-ctor?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo.%2523ctor);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) class.
- the `FileName` property is set to the path of the program you want to open.
- `UseShellExecute` and `CreateNoWindow` are irrelevant here, leave the default.

---

```
using System.Diagnostics;

Process process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo procInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe",
    Arguments = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "[Some File].txt"),
};
process.StartInfo = procInfo;
process.Start();
if (process != null) process.Dispose();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, however this doesnt resolve my issue. at the start of my application i open notepad++ and embed it into my form.

Comment: Where in your question did you mention this or showed that you're using  SetParent? BTW, I don't know why you're doing it, but that's quite a bad idea. Parenting Top Windows always ends up in tragedy. Use a RichTextBox.